# Buttons do not show in the simulator

Tags: swift, uibutton

Buttons do not show in the simulator. I thought that problem could be in invalid images. However i also tried to change buttons` background color, but nothing appeared on the screen...

```
import UIKit

typealias TD = [[UIButton]]

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   func createGameGrid(_ x1: Int, _ x2: Int, _ y1: Int, _ y2: Int, // get coordinates of grid`a angels positions
                        _ cols: Int, _ rows: Int)->TD{

        // grid innicialization...
        var gameGridTemp : TD = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: UIButton(), count: cols), count: rows),
        //x and y means plates` coordinates
        x: Int = 0, y: Int = 0,
        //means the size of each plate on the grid
        plateSize: Int = 40

        print("Plate`s size: \(plateSize)")


        // setting plates` coordinates...
        for i in 0...rows-1{
            for j in 0...cols-1{
                gameGridTemp[i][j].frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: plateSize, height: plateSize)
                //gameGridTemp[i][j].setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "defaultBtn.png"), for: .normal)
                gameGridTemp[i][j].backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                x += plateSize
            }
            y += plateSize
        }

        return gameGridTemp

    }

    func showGrid(_ grid: TD, _ rows: Int, _ cols: Int){
        for i in 0...rows-1{
            for j in 0...cols-1{
                self.view.addSubview(grid[i][j])
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let rows: Int = 5, cols: Int = 4
        //creating the grid
        var gameGrid = createGameGrid(0, 500, 0, 500, cols, rows)
        //func which helps to show the previously created grid up
        showGrid(gameGrid, rows, cols)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use initialise a `Array` using the `init(repeating:count:)` API, the element you specify for repeating will be copied.

This means, the `UIButton` instance will be the same in your whole array! Therefore, every time you modify the array's `[i][j]` element, you actually modify the same `UIButton` instance.

A simple way to resolve this issue, is to create in your loop every time a new instance of `UIButton` and assign it to the right index in your array.

```swift
for i in 0...rows-1 {
            for j in 0...cols-1 {
                var button = UIButton()
                button.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: plateSize, height: plateSize)
                //gameGridTemp[i][j].setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "defaultBtn.png"), for: .normal)
                button.setTitle("foo", for: .normal)
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                gameGridTemp[i][j] = button
                x += plateSize
            }
            y += plateSize
            x = 0

        }
```